# Safari specific scroll bar issue in legacy code

Tags: html, debugging, iframe, safari, scroll

I am trying to debug an issue that is occurring specifically in Safari. On a few pages of a web application, the content is larger than the frame and a scroll bar appears on the right but when the scroll bar moves up or down the content does not scroll with it. So you can "scroll" the scroll bar but the content itself was inaccessible even though the scroll bar was mobile.

The issue only occurs in the "Multi-Process Windows" debug mode option but not in the "Single-Process Windows" option. The scroll bar works perfectly fine in Firefox, IE, and Chrome, just not in Safari. Because there's a lot of legacy code, I'm not quite sure exactly what the actual content is and which specific html elements are relevant. From what I can tell there's an Iframe element, html element, body element, div element, iframe element html element, body element and finally some divs.

*edit* Does it matter if some of the elements within the `<iframe>` have the attribute `scrolling="no"`? I see this on a few of the elements within iframe but my coworker reassures me they don't matter.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding overflow-y: scroll; to the body css?

Comment: I just tried adding it to each major element in the iframe with web inspector and nothing happened. I'm guessing if the scroll bar is already there then that shouldn't be the issue?